# converting emacs calc eqn to latex in org table

Tags: org-mode, calc

Is it possible to convert column 2 to latex in org-table using a command?
It seems that the technology already exists with calc-embed but I don't know how to use it here.

```
  | G | 7*(-2:5)+5*(4:7)                | \frac{2}{35}  |
  | H | 1:3 + 1:6 + 5:12                | \frac{11}{12} |
  #+TBLFM: $3='(calc-eval $2)
```

**Desired input**

```
   | G | 7* \frac{-2}{5} + 5 * \frac{4}{7}      | \frac{2}{35}  |
   | H | \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{5}{12} | \frac{11}{12} |
  #+TBLFM: $3='(calc-eval $2)
```

**Update**
I forgot to mention just in case someone missed it, calc-embedded need to be activated, `calc-embedded-activate`

Comment: I think that `calc-embedded-activate` is misleading here.  From the info: The ‘C-x * a’ (‘calc-embedded-activate’) command scans through the
current buffer and activates all embedded formulas that contain ‘:=’ or
‘=>’ symbols.

Comment: I think this is a nice feature request.  Please post it on the Org mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Have the region `-2:5` in a buffer.

`C-0 C-x * e` activates calc's embedded mode on that region.  Activate calc-latex-language by typing `d L` if not already done.  The marked text has been replaced by `\frac{-2}{5}`.  Key sequence `C-x * e` deactivates embedded mode.

So I think it's possible to write a command that checks for fractions like `-2:5` in a column of an org-table and then applies calc's conversion as pointed out above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a nice try! I'm aware of this possibility. I was more looking for a way to do it for the whole column in one go with a command.